# scraping xml data using import lxml.etree as ElementTree

Tags: python, pandas, xml, web-scraping, elementtree

I am trying to learn how to scrape a website using XML. I am quite familiar with html but I noticed some of the websites I attempt to scrape have XML API's. If I am not mistaken it is faster and fairly simpler to scrape.

I have the following sample code.

```
txt = '''
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DIV5 N="100" TYPE="HEADER">
   <HEAD>100: DIV5 Title</HEAD>
   <AUTH>
      <HED>Authority:</HED>
      <PSPACE>AUTHORITY SPACE</PSPACE>
   </AUTH>
   <SOURCE>
      <HED>Source:</HED>
      <PSPACE>Source Text.</PSPACE>
   </SOURCE>
   <DIV7 N="1" TYPE="SUB">
      <HEAD>1. DIV7Title 1</HEAD>
      <DIV8 N="1.1" TYPE="SECTION">
         <HEAD>1.1 DIV8Title 1</HEAD>
         <P> (1) Text 1</P>
      </DIV8>

      <DIV8 N="1.2" TYPE="SECTION">
         <HEAD>1.2 DIV8Title 2</HEAD>
         <P>(a) text 1 </P>
         <P>(ii) text 2 </P>
         <P>(2) text 2.1 </P>
      </DIV8>

      <DIV8 N="1.3" TYPE="SECTION">
         <HEAD>1.3 DIV8 Title 3</HEAD>
         <P> (ff) text 1 </P>
      </DIV8>
   </DIV7>
   <DIV6 N="A" TYPE="SUBPART">
      <HEAD>Subpart A: DIV6Title 1 </HEAD>
      <DIV7 N="2" TYPE="SUB">
         <HEAD>2 DIV7Title 2</HEAD>
         <DIV8 N="2.1" TYPE="SECTION">
            <HEAD>2.1 DIV8Title 1 </HEAD>
            <P>(a) text 1</P>
            <P>(b) text 2 </P>
            <P>(c) text 3</P>
         </DIV8>

         <DIV8 N="2.2" TYPE="SECTION">
            <HEAD>2.2 DIV8 Title2</HEAD>
            <P> (o) text</P>
         </DIV8>
      </DIV7>
      <DIV7 N="3" TYPE="SUB">
         <HEAD>3. DIV7 Title 3</HEAD>
         <DIV8 N="3.1" TYPE="SECTION">
            <HEAD>3.1 DIV8 Title 1</HEAD>
            <P>(r) text 1</P>
            <P>(s) text 2</P>
         </DIV8>
      </DIV7>
   </DIV6>
   <DIV6 N="B" TYPE="SUBPART">
      <HEAD>Subpart B: DIV6 Title 2</HEAD>
         <DIV8 N="12" TYPE="SECTION">
            <HEAD>12. DIV8 Title 1</HEAD>
            <P>7(a) text </P>
         </DIV8>
   </DIV6>
</DIV5>
'''
```

I have the following code:

```
import lxml.etree as ElementTree

tree = ElementTree.ElementTree(ElementTree.fromstring(txt))
root = tree.getroot()

sub_parts = root.findall(".//DIV6")

for sub in sub_parts:
   l2_title = subpart.find('.//HEAD').text
   .
   .# Unsure what to do after this part
   .
```

Problem I am Having:

1. DIV5 children are `[HEAD, AUTH, SOURCE, DIV7, DIV6, DIV6]`
   The above code seems to only grab DIV6 and its children. The code
   completely skips their DIV7 sibling and its children.
   How can I parse both at the same time?

Ideal Outcome:

| L2Ci | L2Title | L3Ci | L3Title | L4Ci | L4Title | L5Ci | L5Title | L6Ci | L6Title |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | 1. | DIV7Title 1 | 1.1 | DIV8Title 1 |  |  | (1) | Text 1 |
|  |  | 1. | DIV7Title 1 | 1.2 | DIV8Title 2 | (a) | text 1 |  |  |
|  |  | 1. | DIV7Title 1 | 1.2 | DIV8Title 2 | (ii) | text 2 |  |  |
|  |  | 1. | DIV7Title 1 | 1.2 | DIV8Title 2 | (ii) | text 2 | (2) | text 2.1 |
|  |  | 1. | DIV7Title 1 | 1.3 | DIV8Title 3 | (ff) | text 1 |  |  |
| A | DIV6Title 1 | 2. | DIV7Title 2 | 2.1 | DIV8Title 1 | (a) | text 1 |  |  |
| A | DIV6Title 1 | 2. | DIV7Title 2 | 2.1 | DIV8Title 1 | (b) | text 2 |  |  |
| A | DIV6Title 1 | 2. | DIV7Title 2 | 2.1 | DIV8Title 1 | (c) | text 3 |  |  |
| A | DIV6Title 1 | 2. | DIV7Title 2 | 2.2 | DIV8Title 2 | (o) | text 1 |  |  |
| A | DIV6Title 1 | 3. | DIV7Title 3 | 3.1 | DIV8Title 3 | (r) | text 1 |  |  |
| A | DIV6Title 1 | 3. | DIV7Title 3 | 3.1 | DIV8Title 3 | (s) | text 2 |  |  |
| B | DIV6Title 2 |  |  | 12 | DIV8Title 1 | (a) | text |  |  |

Thank You!

Comment: **What would be the most efficient way to...** is off-topic (not allowed), because it is asking for opinions. Please review [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [Don't advise on off-topic questions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/), [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [ask], [tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to find tags by name, you can process all tags "recursively", e.g. with [`.iter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.iter)

You can keep track of the information you need to build a "row".

In this case, each time a `<P>` tag is encountered, the "row" is considered complete, and you can store the result.

Something like:

```
columns = [
   'L2Ci', 'L2Ci', 'L2Title', 'L3Ci', 'L3Title', 
   'L4Ci', 'L4Title', 'L5Ci', 'L5Title', 'L6Ci', 
   'L6Title'
]

row = dict.fromkeys(columns)
rows = []

tag_type = None

for item in tree.iter():
   if item.attrib.get('TYPE', '') == 'SUBPART':
      # New sub-part, empty out all previously seen values
      for key in row:
         row[key] = None
      row['L2Ci'] = item.attrib['N']
      tag_type = 'L2Title'

   if item.attrib.get('TYPE', '') == 'SUB':
      row['L3Ci'] = item.attrib['N']
      tag_type = 'L3Title'
  
   if item.attrib.get('TYPE', '') == 'SECTION':
      row['L4Ci'] = item.attrib['N']
      tag_type = 'L4Title'
  
   if item.tag == 'HEAD':
      if tag_type is not None:
         row[tag_type] = item.text.strip()
 
   if item.tag == 'P':
      row['P'] = item.text.strip()
      rows.append(row.copy())
```

You can then create a dataframe: `df = pd.DataFrame(rows)`

| L2Ci | L2Title | L3Ci | L3Title | L4Ci | L4Title | L5Ci | L5Title | L6Ci | L6Title | P |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | 1 | 1. DIV7Title 1 | 1.1 | 1.1 DIV8Title 1 |  |  |  |  | (1) Text 1 |
|  |  | 1 | 1. DIV7Title 1 | 1.2 | 1.2 DIV8Title 2 |  |  |  |  | (a) text 1 |
|  |  | 1 | 1. DIV7Title 1 | 1.2 | 1.2 DIV8Title 2 |  |  |  |  | (ii) text 2 |
|  |  | 1 | 1. DIV7Title 1 | 1.2 | 1.2 DIV8Title 2 |  |  |  |  | (2) text 2.1 |
|  |  | 1 | 1. DIV7Title 1 | 1.3 | 1.3 DIV8 Title 3 |  |  |  |  | (ff) text 1 |
| A | Subpart A: DIV6Title 1 | 2 | 2 DIV7Title 2 | 2.1 | 2.1 DIV8Title 1 |  |  |  |  | (a) text 1 |
| A | Subpart A: DIV6Title 1 | 2 | 2 DIV7Title 2 | 2.1 | 2.1 DIV8Title 1 |  |  |  |  | (b) text 2 |
| A | Subpart A: DIV6Title 1 | 2 | 2 DIV7Title 2 | 2.1 | 2.1 DIV8Title 1 |  |  |  |  | (c) text 3 |
| A | Subpart A: DIV6Title 1 | 2 | 2 DIV7Title 2 | 2.2 | 2.2 DIV8 Title2 |  |  |  |  | (o) text |
| A | Subpart A: DIV6Title 1 | 3 | 3. DIV7 Title 3 | 3.1 | 3.1 DIV8 Title 1 |  |  |  |  | (r) text 1 |
| A | Subpart A: DIV6Title 1 | 3 | 3. DIV7 Title 3 | 3.1 | 3.1 DIV8 Title 1 |  |  |  |  | (s) text 2 |
| B | Subpart B: DIV6 Title 2 |  |  | 12 | 12. DIV8 Title 1 |  |  |  |  | 7(a) text |

You can implement the rest of the logic to populate the `L5-6` tags from the `P` text.